# Calling a function which is inside a exported function (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

In a Node/Next.js environment, I have a utility function exported like this:

```
export async function MyFunction(one, two, three) {
    var a, b

    // do some logic / save to context store, etc.

}
```

and I'm using it inside my pages/components like `MyFunction("one",false,"three")` ,
if I now have a inner function like:

```
export async function MyFunction(one, two, three) {
   var a, b

   function MySecondFunction(){
      a = 'a new value'
      b = 'b new value'
      // update some context stores
   }

   // do some logic / save to context store, etc.

   if(...){
      MySecondFunction()
   }

}
```

how can I run `MySecondFunction()` from outside (from my pages/components)? I found some examples but it all imply to return, the difference is here I don't have to return anything from either `MyFunction` or `MySecondFunction`

**EDIT:** to give more context, `MySecondFunction()` is a sort of "**reset**" of all the stores and variables set within `MyFunction()`. As a store management library I'm using Zustand, and I'm loading various stores, so I was wondering if I can call this "reset" (MySecondFunction) from the outside without having to require all the stores again in each component from which I'm willing to do the reset.

Comment: do you just want to execute mysecondfunction and not any other part of myfunction ?

Comment: yea, but as stated MySecondFunction modifies some variables which are used inside MyFunction and changes stores which are required already inside MyFunction so I'd rather not require it in a new function again just for that

Comment: @NathanBernard - There's *different* `MySecondFunction` created by every call to `MyFunction`. So if you're trying to use it independently of a call to `MyFunction`, how would you know which one to use? (That's why you see examples of this involving *returning* the inner function -- you know which one to use because it's the one you got from an earlier call to `MyFunction`.) Logically, it doesn't make sense to try to treat a function only created (and recreated) by calls to another function *independently* of that other function. How do you plan to use `MySecondFunction`? That may clariify. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also return the second function.

```js
export async MyFunction(one, two, three) {
  // do some logic

  function MySecondFunction(four, five, six) {
    // do more logic
  }
  
  // execute the second function from inside MyFunction (can be omitted)
  // MySecondFunction()

  // return the second function to be able to run it at a later time from outside.
  return MySecondFunction
}

//call just the first function
MyFunction("one", "two", "three");

//run the second function right after the first function
MyFunction("one", "two", "three")("four", "five", "six");

// if you want to execute the second function at a later time, you can execute MyFunction 
// and assign its return value (which is MySecundFunction) to a variable and execute it later.
let mySecondFunction = MyFunction("one", "two", "three");
mySecondFunction("four", "five", "six");
```

I hope this is what you mean.

Comment: MyFunction has not any real return, it's a utility function, it makes things happen inside of it when called from the outside. My idea was to just run MySecondFunction() without running the whole MyFunction, does it even make sense?

Comment: You can return MySecondFuntion from within MyFunction. When you run MyFunction, you can save the returned value (MySecondFunction) inside a variable, which you can run at a later time without having to run MyFunction again. This is in the lines of the code I posted. I just don't know if this the behavior you want.